# No known instance method for selector 'appendPartWithFileData:name:fileName:mimeType:' Rest Kit 0.26

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm getting this annoying compiler error even though the autocomplete gives me that same method (in the title).

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h"

-(NSMutableURLRequest*)configureConnectionForImageUpload:(UIImage*)picture forPath:(NSString*)path{

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture, 1.0);

    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",path,[NSDate date]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] multipartFormRequestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:path parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

        if(imageData && picture){
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:file mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        }
    }];

    return request;

}
```

I installed it through cocoapods. pod 'RestKit' and my version is 0.39.0
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `AFMultipartFormData` is part of  `AFNetworking`. It's unclear how to link it (look at the installation guide) since the dependency didn't appeared clearly on the PodSpec of RestKit, but you need to have AFNetworking.

Comment: I believe it is included since it shows up on the pods installed

Comment: Import the AFNetworking header corresponding then? There is a bunch of import importing other headers in Reskit.h, look if one does correctly import the AFNetworking header. If not, import it manually.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the header file where this method declared is included.

Comment: RestKit includes it.. AHTTPClient.h

Comment: Might be some linker problem. Are you able to Jump to Definition of "AFMultipartFormData" from here?